# Google result displays invalid heading text

Tags: seo, google, google-search

Where does Google take the highlighted text in the below image from?

[image]

Below is the header section of the page.

[image]

The page title clearly states 'St Vincent’s Private Hospital, Werribee' so, I'm not sure where 'St Vincent’s Private Hospital Sydney' is coming from.

Any ideas on where and how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That information isn't about the page.  It is about the site.  Google thinks that "Saint Vincent Private Hospital Sydney" is the brand name rather than more appropriate "Saint Vincent Private Hospitals."

Google uses multiple source to automatically determine the brand name.  I've seen them take it from:

- The home page title
- The logo alt text on the home page
- Text embedded inside the logo's SVG image file
- A Google My Business listing

That last one appears to be what is happening here.  This business listing is the problem:

[image: Saint Vincent Private Hospital Sydney Business Listing]

That business listing has the home page of your site listed as its web page rather than the more appropriate `/hospitals/sydney` subdirectory. Because of that, Google is taking the name of that particular hospital to be brand name of your entire site.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say most feedback from the folks on here is quite relevant. The last message from  Stephen where he says > "That business listing has the home page of your site listed as its web page rather than the more appropriate /hospitals/sydney subdirectory. Because of that, Google is taking the name of that particular hospital to be brand name of your entire site." is a great tip, worth exploring.

Google can get weird sometimes, I find that Bing is more accurate with those elements (no matter what is in the local page settings), respecting what the webmaster puts in the source code instead, instead of using 24-7 the RankBrain AI which has many flaws. Here are some ideas:

1- Have you considered adding the word "Melbourne" next to it or "Victoria (VIC)"? so it adds more relation to the state of Victoria, instead of Sydney (NSW) which was mentioned. It does (as mentioned by Stephen) seem to be a brand assumption by the look of it.

[image: screenshot of hospital in google]

and this one

[[image: victoria bing2]

2- Bing is more accurate than Google as you can see (see screenshot)

[image: bing image of hospital]

3- With that said, there's some local knowledge of the VIC location
as per this local listing, it sends me to this page
https://www.svph.org.au/hospitals/werribee (screenshot)

[image]